# What are the permissions required in profile to create an object in salesforce

Tags: custom-object, permissions

I would like to know the permission(s) required to create an object in Salesforce, I've created a custom profile and enabled **View All Data** and **Modify All Data** permissions but still, I'm not able to create a table from UI or API. here is the behaviour from UI and API

UI :- I don't see 'New Custom Object' button to create an object, I'm sharing the snapshot below.

API :- I'm getting below error message while creating custom object

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id in statement

Can anyone let me know the necessary permission(s) to create an object?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You need System Administrator profile. That's it. I would suggest you to check logged in user profile.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Custom Object in Salesforce, a user needs the Customize Application permission under System Permissions.